# How do I calculate the ratio within a variable by group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consisting of:

```
HouseholdID <- c("1", "2","2", "3", "3", "4")
ItemNo <- c("23", "25", "23", "26", "23", "24")
ItemPrice <- c(200, 300, 200, 500, 200, 900)
TotalHouseholdExpenses <- c(200, 500, 500, 700, 700, 900)

df  <- data.frame(HouseholdID, ItemNo, ItemPrice, TotalHouseholdExpenses)
```

That's to say Household 1 bought item 23 and spent $200, Household 2 bought items 25 and 23, and spent $500, etc. If Items 23 and 24 were considered 'temptation goods', and I would like to know what % of each household's total household expenses consisted of temptation goods, how would I calculate this and create a new variable of this ratio? Thank you.

Comment: What is a 'ratio of item 23 and 24 together'? What would be the right answer for the example you gave?

Comment: @Bernhard Sorry for the lack of clarity, I mean items 23 and 24 are considered 'temptation goods', so I would like to know what % of total household expenses is temptation goods for each household.

Answer (score 0):

if ratio is `ItemPrice/TotalHouseholdExpenses` the `dcast` works for you

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(HouseholdID,ItemNo,ItemPrice,TotalHouseholdExpenses)

dcast(dt, HouseholdID + TotalHouseholdExpenses ~ ItemNo, value.var = 'ItemPrice') %>% 
  mutate(across(`23`:`26`, ~ .x /TotalHouseholdExpenses))
```

or to not have to specify columns by hand:

```
dcast(dt, HouseholdID + TotalHouseholdExpenses ~ ItemNo, value.var = 'ItemPrice') %>% 
  mutate(across(3:(2+length(unique(ItemNo))), ~ .x /TotalHouseholdExpenses))
```

```
output:
   HouseholdID TotalHouseholdExpenses        23 24  25        26
1:           1                    200 1.0000000 NA  NA        NA
2:           2                    500 0.4000000 NA 0.6        NA
3:           3                    700 0.2857143 NA  NA 0.7142857
4:           4                    900        NA  1  NA        NA
```

at last with % format

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)

dt <- data.table(HouseholdID,ItemNo,ItemPrice,TotalHouseholdExpenses)

dcast(dt, HouseholdID + TotalHouseholdExpenses ~ ItemNo, value.var = 'ItemPrice') %>% 
  mutate(across(3:(2+length(unique(ItemNo))), ~ label_percent()(.x /TotalHouseholdExpenses)))


output:
   HouseholdID TotalHouseholdExpenses   23   24   25   26
1:           1                    200 100% <NA> <NA> <NA>
2:           2                    500  40% <NA>  60% <NA>
3:           3                    700  29% <NA> <NA>  71%
4:           4                    900 <NA> 100% <NA> <NA>
```